# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 167 path $.progress

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-firestore

I have read couple of answers based on that particular problem. and I am aware of that in my Custom object(AssignmentData), it is expecting array, But it is actually an array on firestore with the name of progress as well.
**Here is the firestore document**

```
assignmentId
       "irfan 1671299952415"
endTime
        "1671991147130"
exStatus
        0
game_nameId
        2
groupName
       "Math 101"
levelId
        "1"
number_of_exercises
        10

progress
        []
```

sectionId
"1"

**My Custom Object**

```
public class Assignmentsdata implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("exStatus")
@Expose
private Integer exStatus;
@SerializedName("groupName")
@Expose
private String groupName;
@SerializedName("teacherId")
@Expose
private String teacherId;
@SerializedName("game_nameId")
@Expose
private Integer gameNameId;
@SerializedName("levelId")
@Expose
private String levelId;
@SerializedName("students")
@Expose
private List<PersonModel> students = null;
@SerializedName("progress")
@Expose
private ArrayList<String> progress = null;

public Integer getExStatus() {
    return exStatus;
}

public void setExStatus(Integer exStatus) {
    this.exStatus = exStatus;
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public String getTeacherId() {
    return teacherId;
}

public void setTeacherId(String teacherId) {
    this.teacherId = teacherId;
}

public Integer getGame_nameId() {
    return gameNameId;
}

public void setGameNameId(Integer gameNameId) {
    this.gameNameId = gameNameId;
}



public ArrayList<String> getProgress() {
    return progress;
}

public void setProgress(ArrayList<String> progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
}
```

*There is an array and i am expecting an array then what is causing an error?*

```
 DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            try {
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                String json = gson.toJson(document.getData());

     // tried map directly from document but outcome is same.
    //Assignmentsdata assignmentsdata = document.toObject(Assignmentsdata.class);
                                Assignmentsdata assignmentsdata = gson.fromJson(json, Assignmentsdata.class);

                                if (assignmentsdata != null) {
                                    filtered_invitation_list.add(assignmentsdata);
                                }
                            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                               Log.d("Failure", "No exception here: ", 
                            }


                            if (finalI == teachers.size() - 1) {
                                try {
```

**Error shows in Exception below not above where it is actually getting the object.**

```
 consumer.accept(filtered_invitation_list);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.d("Failure", "Here is get the exception: ", e);
                                }

                            }
```

Comment: data is coming from firestore, the picture I have attached is the data stored there. Document.getData is the data coming from firestore(firebase).

Comment: Why are you using Gson instead of directly mapping a document into an object of type `Assignmentsdata`? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo , The outcome is the same. I have tried direct mapping as well.  Which is a document.toObject(Assignmentsdata.class);  Error is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked: What's the value of `gson.toJson(document.getData())`?

Comment: @tgdavies The picture showing the value of gson.toJson(document.getData()). The object you can see in the picture is the outcome of the document.getData.

Comment: But what actual JSON string does it get turned into?

Comment: It will be turned inot an Object called Assignmentsdata, i have made it bold as a custom object.

Comment: I mean the String `json`. What is the value of that?

Comment: Say you say that `document.toObject(Assignmentsdata.class)` produces a `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes and I get that error at this line consumer.accept. I made a heading with bold text where I get an error.

Comment: @AlexMamo Here is the complete error. Cached document data: {exStatus=0, groupName=Math 101, teacherId=irfan, game_nameId=2, levelId=1, students=[{teacherName=irfan, studentName=Alli, fullName=Teacher, status=2}], progress=[], startTime=1671299947129, sectionId=1, endTime=1671991147130, assignmentId=irfan 1671299952415, number_of_exercises=10}  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 167 path $.progress

Comment: @tgdavies I posted the whole object that I receive, with an error in the above comment.

Comment: If that's the value of the string, it is not valid JSON. But I don't think that's the value of the string.

Comment: That's the Jason Firebase provide, plus I attached the error with it too. Please if you could post the correct one json.

Comment: What type of the object is `consumer`? Btw, mapping a document into an object of type Assignmentsdata, can never throw such an exception.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for your answer and time.  I am posting an answer. why i received this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the above error at this code.

```
consumer.accept(filtered_invitation_list);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("Failure", "Here is get the exception: ", e);
                            }
                        }
```

> But there was no problem on Mapping the objects coming from firestore, The problem was with ViewModel and observing the list of Objects coming from firestore. I had some Assignments already which I saved locally, because of a mismatch of the Object structure or fields, it was giving an error in my Fragment class, but the error was observed in my repository. I know its a little tricky why the error coming back to the repository.

```
viewModel.getActiveAssignments.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), this::getAssignmentsData);
private void getAssignmentsData(ArrayList<Assignmentsdata> assignmentsdata) {
    // get the data saved locally and merge with new incoming.
```